# Fine-Uploader - retry with "scaling" and "hideScaled" only sends original image

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm calling Fine-Uploader to upload images with client-side scaling, and I'm hiding the scaled images.  If there's a bug in my server-side receiver CGI script then all uploads fail and the image shows a "Retry" button, but clicking it (after fixing the bug!) only causes the failed original image to be resent.  The scaled images are lost.  Here's the fine-uploader call.  What am I missing to get it to resend the scaled images if they failed?

```
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: 'cgi/fine-uploader.cgi',
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: PLACEHOLDERS+'waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: PLACEHOLDERS+'not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        // request client-size scaling - causes upload of "image (size).jpg" in addition to "image.jpg"
        scaling: {
            sizes: [
                { name: "thumb", maxSize: 200 },
                { name: "popup", maxSize: 600 },
            ],
            hideScaled: true
        },
        autoUpload: false
    });

    $('#trigger-upload').click(function() {
        $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
};
```

Comment: fine-uploader version is 5.11.9

Answer (score 0):

From the [scaled images documentation page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html):

> Since they will not be represented in the UI, this means that they cannot be deleted, canceled, or manually retried via Fine Uploader's default UI. Failures of these scaled versions will obviously not be apparent to users by default if you elect to hide them from the UI.

If you want to manually retry hidden scaled images, you'll need to get a handle on their IDs and use the [retry API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#retry).

Comment: But they ARE represented in the UI.  If you inspect the HTML there's an <LI> element for each hidden file, with an added class `qq-hidden-forever` and attribute `style="display:none"` compared to the visible ones.  Fine-Uploader must know they're related to the image that was scaled, so it should be possible to link the visible RETRY button to the failed scaled image uploads as part of the standard Fine-Uploader behaviour.  It looks like that isn't available right now, though, so I'll have to work out something using the retry API method.  Thanks for the link to that.